# Конвертация строки в массив

Tags: java

Мне нужно конвертировать строку текста в массив и чтобы на консоли показывало каждый символ строки и десятичное значение этого символа. Не могу найти ошибку

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Abcdefg";
        char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();

        for (char c : cArray ) {
            char myChar = str.charAt(c);            
            int myInt = (int)myChar;
            System.out.println(c + myInt);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем это: char myChar = str.charAt(c); ?

Comment: Мне кажется, вам надо прочитать полностью какую-нибудь книжку по Java, тогда такие вопросы отпадут сразу, ибо налицо банальное непонимание основ языка.

Comment: это не код, а ппц =)

Comment: Товарищи @Gorets и @VioLet, если человек учится, зачем же так жестоко? Вопрос задан ведь корректно.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен с @Dex, сам только что хотел то же самое написать. 

Недопонимание языка (точнее методов String) у автора наблюдается, но идея работоспособная.

Другой вопрос, что для печати символов строки и их кодов получение массива символов из строки ненужно. Их можно просто последовательно брать из строки и печатать.

Comment: @Dex, да вроде не жестоко, просто совет дал. Иначе ведь может появится привычка при каждом новом затруднении не пытаться найти информацию в тех же книгах, а сюда писать. Причем "затруднения" будут не серьезные, а просто из-за непонимания принципов основных.

Comment: @VioLet, согласен.

Answer (score 3):

@Luchnik, `char myChar = str.charAt(c);`   это Вы зря. А вот так (почти как у Вас) работать будет

```
    for (char c : cArray ) {
       int myInt = c;
       System.out.println("'"+c+"'  " + myInt);
    }

'A'  65
'b'  98
'c'  99
'd'  100
'e'  101
'f'  102
'g'  103
```

Я немного изменил `println()`, чтобы вывод красивей был.